# Let me squeak a phase four in there

Tags: word-usage

> Let me squeak a phase four in there.
> There is no squeaking of phase four.

What's the meaning of those phrases (squeak sth in / squeak) ? Does it mean inform ? (It's always sunny in Philadelphia)

Comment: It doesn't make sense.  "To squeak" is to make a squeaking sound. I think this could be an error. Did you misunderstand what was being said? Perhaps it is supposed to be "squeeze"?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the comments, it seems a lot of native speakers don't find "squeak in" in this sense idiomatic. However, I do find the first sentence idiomatic. The meaning of "squeak in" here is somewhere between "sneak in" (add something covertly) and "squeeze in" (add something that barely fits). The second sentence is a playful inversion of the first, loose with grammar in the same way that "there was no fun to be had" is a playful way of saying "(someone) didn't have fun".

Is "squeak in" a regionalism? I don't think so. American? Maybe. Here's an example from Washington state, on the other side of the country from me:

> Anyone else trying to squeak in some last minute camping before the weather turns? Had an awesome trip last week on the Olympic Peninsula of Washington State. — [beardedbeernerd on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/traveltrailers/comments/pmitzx/anyone_else_trying_to_squeak_in_some_last_minute/)

Here's another example, also likely from the US (does anyone else care about American sports?):

> I break down some of the hottest topics in the NFL and squeak in a little NBA as well. — [The Big Red Express Podcast (description)](https://web.archive.org/web/20220708234501/https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/59-nfl-hot-topics/id931542419?i=1000537735130)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard expression. It is a mixture of "squeak" = speak in a high-pitched, quiet, timid voice (and perhaps, "squeak", a sound made when two unlubricated things rub against each other). And "squeeze in" = insert in a small gap.

The mixing of these senses is a pun, and done as a joke by the speaker.

Comment: what's the meaning of those sentences ?

Comment: Yes and no, I think.  It might be a new and informal usage, and maybe a mixture of *squeak* and *squeeze*, but it's not unique to this speaker.

Comment: For example, [(the) Commission “squeaked in” right under the deadline to narrow the megaproject to three sites](https://www.postsouth.com/story/news/2022/06/27/mississippi-river-bridge-site-choice-depends-environmental-studies/7747814001/) or [Gillum had squeaked in and had beaten a moderate to get the nomination](https://www.newyorker.com/podcast/politics-and-more/dexter-filkins-on-the-rise-of-ron-desantis), or [a few survey participants squeaked in at less than 20 kWh/sf/year.](https://www.environmentalleader.com/2022/06/hospitals-use-less-fossil-fuel-but-energy-use-hasnt-slipped-much/)

Comment: Those examples are slightly different and idiomatic.  To "squeak in" in that sense is to achieve something just before a cut-off or deadline.